# ajax and javascript - function return my null but when i console.dir i see the data

Tags: javascript, ajax

why when i try to return value from function i get undefined?
i know i use void function but what happen if i want get value form function like that?

thanks!

```
 var t = getdata();
 console.dir("test:" + t); -- > undefined

 function getdata() {
            var list = "";
            $.ajax("api/publish",
                { method: "get" })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.dir(response); --> print the response 
                });
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Your console command runs *before* the ajax reply arrives in the browser. The ajax request is async, that's why you have to use `.then()` and pass a callback function. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/yfqckwzo/

Answer (score 0):

javascript is an asynchronous programming language and you are doing an ajax call so on ajax call by default async will be true so you  have to try with `async : false` on ajax call. Just give try may be it will give luck